# Is it possible to create a custom overlay with OpenStreetMap and use it on ios device?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox, tilemill

I stacked with this problem. I've tried MapBox, but my source files are not so compatible with it.

I have a lot of data from here :http://skimap.org/SkiAreas/view/1022#open_ski_maps. (kml and osm files). The MapBox(TileMill) is not so compatible with KML you have to transform it and you can't use custom styles for different path types.

Is it possible to create an overlay from these files and show them on OpenStreetMap under iOS platform ? 
Something similar like this: http://skimap.org/SkiAreas/view/1022#google_maps but on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

1. TileMill should work with KML. You can also consider converting your KML to another format using something like https://github.com/mapbox/togeojson
2. On iOS, you want to use the [MapBox mobile tools](http://mapbox.com/mobile) to bring in a TileMill map, or even parse the KML client-side with something like [Simple KML](https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML).

Comment: Thanks for quick your answer. The TileMill doesn't support KML files which contain points and lines. After I'd removed the points from the file above, the TileMill drawn the lines to the map. However I wasn't able to refer the name or style like this, I'd tried every possibilities: #imported_id { [Name="Pedestrian"] { line-color:#000000; } }

Comment: Converting the KML file to something else looks like a good solution :).

Comment: Unfortunately, I encountered an other problem. In my case I have to draw approximately 1000 paths around the world, to the map. If I put them to one or more files and I upload these files to the MapBox via TileMill the size of the cache will be ~20GB. I tried with an example what was 20MB. Do you know any solution for these problems?  Thank!